# Checkmarx found library which don't have in android project

Tags: android, checkmarx, sast

Checkmarx OSA found:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
Your version is outdated
However when I scan dependency I can't find as we have any jackson libraries in project.
Do you know what problem could be?

Comment: did you check if the file exists in the file system? it may not be part of the project but it may be in the same folder as the project

Comment: yes, checked. For example it found com.speedment.common:collection which we don't have 100% in our project

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a library including this outdated version. To see a full list of dependencies run `./gradlew app:dependencies`, which will return something similar to:

```
| +--- androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0
| | +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
| | \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
| +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0
| | +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0 (*)
| | +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
```

You can then see which library is using an outdated version of jackson-databind.

Comment: I scan dependency I can't find as we have any jackson libraries in project